# Why don't the <li> elements align properly horizontally?

Tags: alignment, html-lists

I made a navigation menu with an unordered list, it contains  tags inside them span and one more span inside the first - with display: block. For some reason the list items don't align horizontally. Here is the code to see what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Shoshin and Sumikiri's Website</title>
<style>
*{margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border: 0;
 }
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #30b4bc;
 background-image: url('Green-pattern-cat.png');
 }
.wrapper{
 width: 900px;
 margin: 30px auto;
 }
img{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
ul{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 50px 0;
 }
li{
 background: url('Patch-menu.png') no-repeat;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 40px;
 }
li:last-child{
 margin-right:0;
 }
a{
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 width: 134px;
 height: 134px;
 }
a>span{
 font: italic bold 24px/35px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
 color:black;
 display: block;
 width: 108px;
 height: 106px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 7px;
 }
span span{
 font: 14px/14px Corbel, sans-serif;
 color: #7a3225;
 display: block;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <img src="Main-image.png" alt="Шоши и Суми"/>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>Шоши<span>Или какви ги свърши Шошката досега</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>Суми<span>Или какви ги свърши Суми досега</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>Новини<span>Последни постижения и приключения</span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>Още<span>Какво още пропуснахте от светските новости</span></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, the list items are with display: inline-block so they appear next to each other. Everything looks fine until I put smaller font size on the span elements inside - 16 px and it's fine, 14 px - and they go up and down.

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us how they *do* align currently. If they're different heights and not aligning from the top, you might have success adding (though the CSS elite might hate us both for it) `vertical-align:top;`.

Comment: It already does align horizontally. Take a look
[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11469196/draw.PNG)

Comment: Here is an example, I added a black border around everything so it's more easily seen - jsbin.com/ihikeb/1/edit. The li elements are all the same size. The problem appears after I put smaller font on the span elements inside them - it's ok with 16 px but with 14 px they go up and down.

Comment: @user2025846 From your example I can't see the problem you describe, is this in a specific browser? I used Chrome to view your example.

Comment: @Grant Thomas - I tried adding `vertical-align:top;` and it worked, Thanks a lot though I still don't understand why this happened... I am  also with Chrome. It looks as the span align according to each other because they are different number of lines of text so they align to the bottom line.

Comment: @user2025846 Okay, well, glad you're sorted.